# How can I disable/enable LineRenderer on mouse click on ogameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem is that that line is always false:

```
private void OnMouseOver()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        line.enabled = !line;
        if (line.enabled == true)
            CreatePoints();
    }
}
```

I want that when I click on the `GameObject` once the line will be enabled true and then `CreatePoints()` and once clicking again line will be false and won't create the points.

UPDATE:

Added a counter so the default state when running the game will be true and then it will switch to false/true.

```
int clickcount = 0;
    private void OnMouseOver()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (clickcount == 0)
            {
                line.enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                line.enabled = !line.enabled;
            }
            if (line.enabled)
                CreatePoints();

            clickcount ++;
        }
    }
```

This is working fine but is it a good way to use a counter like that ?

Comment: So what is your "!line"? Is it boolean? or your line renderer? If its line renderer try it as 'line.enabled = !line.enabled;'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
 {
   line.enabled = !line.enabled;
   if (line.enabled)
     CreatePoints();
 }
```

You cannot access enabled/disabled state of the gameobject directly. You need to retrieve it using **.enabled** and set the opposite of it to toggle on & off.

Comment: This is working but it seems like it's starting by default as false line.enabled = false  when I click on the object first time. I need to click twice to enable it true first time running the game. How can I make that when running the game on the first click it will enable it true ?

Comment: Solved by adding a counter. Edited and updated my question with what I did. Is it a good way to do it ?

Comment: Yes, the counter seems also one of the ways. Not a big issue. If you dont want counter then you can set the default state of it in start function as line.enabled = false; Remember you have the line renderer enabled in your scene by default. Alternatively You can also disable the component in scene instead of writing in start and let the controller script take care of enabling and disabling the line render.

Comment: If you think the answer solved the your issue you can mark and close it down :)